# How to Convert a String to an array in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, redis

In the actual project I'm working on,I'm using redis for memory,but it only accepts strings,bytes,int and float as values,so as I need to store arrays,I transform an array like `[{'hi':'there'}]` into an string like this  `"[{'hi':'there'}]"`,but my question is: how I convert this string into an actual array??? because when I use the tradicional list() method,the only thing I get as result is :
`['[', '{', "'", 'e', 'a', 'e', "'", ':', ' ', "'", 'c', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'o', ' ', 'v', 'a', 'i', "'", '}', ']']`

Comment: use JSON to serialize and deserialize this kind of data

Comment: `json.loads(data)`

Comment: @deadshot that actually won't work with the string: `"[{'hi':'there'}]"` you'd need `eval`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the original list-of-dicts back, you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
xxx = [{'hi':'there'}]
s = str(xxx)
print(s)
pring(type(s))
yyy = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(yyy)
print(type(yyy))
```

Output:

```
[{'hi': 'there'}]
<class 'str'>
[{'hi': 'there'}]
<class 'list'>
```

The suggestion to use JSON is also a good one.  Be sure to use `json.dumps` instead of just converting to string, so you get the right kinds of quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks só much !!!